# Gmail is not receiving emails sent from Google App + PHPMailer

Tags: gmail, dns, google-apps, phpmailer, spf

I'm using [PHPMailer 5.2.0](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list) and [Google Apps](http://apps.google.com) for my domain email (let say my domain is mydomain.com).

Email sending works well, but Gmail accounts are not receiving the emails.

- Email sent to Yahoo: *Delivered*
- Email sent to Hotmail: *Delivered*
- Email sent to Gmail: *Not Delivered*

All sent emails appear in Sent Folder of Google App email.

It seems Gmail rejects the emails before it arrives even in Spam folder, doesn't it?

I read about [SPF](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33786) and am trying to [create SPF](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723) record. There are 4 fields for TXT record: Name, TTL, Type, and TXT Data. I'm not sure with Name field, should it be mydomain.com?

Comment: I'm not sure with Name field, should it be mydomain.com? name field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the name of the entry is that of your mail domain (the part after the @). Depending on you DNS software or the administration interface of your domain, you may need to end it with a period:

```
Name: mydomain.com or mydomain.com.
TTL: 86400 
Type: TXT
TXT for Google Apps: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

For example, Google returns the following SPF data (though this example is not for a Google Apps hosted MX):

```
$ dig google.com TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     3189    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"
```

But since you use Google Apps, your SPF entry needs to conform their SMTP settings. Follow [Google instructions for SPF records](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723).

Comment: Okay, SPF works fine and GMail is receving my emails. It takes couple hours to take changes. Thanks jjmontes!